# How to make a content to align after wrapper?

Tags: html, alignment, wrapper

I'm trying to position the contents:
g_image5 which I use it like a background of the entire wrapper
image7 which is the banner over the g_image5
text3 its a paragraph and I have align it in the middle of the wrapper
On my resolution it shows up on the middle but on a higher resolution for example it shows up in the left. I think its because when I aligned it with left:28,5% it goes after the html size which is 100% width.
So my question is: how should I write on the wrapper so that the content to be positioned after it?

```css
html
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" width=100% z-index:-1>
    <div id="g_image5" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left: 23%; top: 18%;   
width:55%;  z-index:0"><img src="images/content2.jpg" alt="" title="" border=0   
width=100% height=150%></div>
    <div id="image7" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:38%; top:20%;    
width:25%; height:13%; z-index:3"><img src="images/2.png" alt="" title="" border=0  
width=100% height=100%></div>
    <div id="text3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:28.5%; top:40%;      
width:50%; height:20%; z-index:3">
        <div class="wpmd">
            <div><font face="Tahoma" class="ws13">Here is a paragraph and here's also the problem</font></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you actually like the content to be positioned? In the middle or to the left?

Comment: i want it in the middle of the g_image5 wich is the background of the wrapper

Comment: please don't use inline styles

Answer (score 0):

in your case the problem is with this combination:

```
#g_image5 {
    width: 55%;
    left: 23%;
    top: 18%;
}
```

Instead you should do something like this, which will center all elements **inside your wrapper** and text inside **horizontally**:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

then to have a scaleable image, just do something along these lines:

```
#g_image5 {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
```

An alternative is to avoid **img** overall and have a picture as a background in CSS:

```
#g_image5 {
    background: url(/*path to your img */) no-repeat center center;
}
```